# My PC comes out of hybernation on its own

Tags: power

Does anyone know what wake source 0 means? Please no diagnostic steps - just what is wake source 0.  I.E.- What device it is referring to if it is a code to some device or procedure. I went to the Microsoft Server page because someone else had asked the same question and the Microsoft tech sent him through a bunch of diagnostics but NEVER answered the question. I just need the question answered - please. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

The reason people couldn't answer your question without diagnostics is that wake source zero isn't really informative. One common cause is that automatic maintenance is being run.

Open Task Scheduler. (You can type in the Start menu/screen for it, or find it in Administrative Tools.) Expand *Task Scheduler Library*, then *Microsoft*, then *Windows*, and select *TaskScheduler*. If any of those tasks show a last run time around when your computer woke unexpectedly (at night, say), right-click them and choose *Disable*.